if ($request->user() && ! $request->user()->subscribed('prod_QbjA3oKZmzyBAj')) {return redirect('subscribe');} always return true
This maybe a silly question but i had to ask, I am using laravel 11, where i am making a subscription page using laravel cashier (stripe) and when I'm making a page that only users who have subscribed can access the page so i am using a middleware PayingCustomer.php in that i am using the if condition as mentioned here.
this is the code of middleware:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PayingCustomer
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if ($request->user() && ! $request->user()->subscribed('prod_QbjA3oKZmzyBAj')) {
            // This user is not a paying customer...
            return redirect('subscribe');
        }
 
        return $next($request);
    }
}


the if condition always return true regardless the user subscribed or not.
My Checkout controller:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request, string $plan = 'price_1PkViISH1mJpX0PlYoCRH74L')
    {
        
        return $request->user()
            ->newSubscription('prod_QbjA3oKZmzyBAj', $plan)
            ->checkout([
                'success_url' => route('success'),
                'cancel_url' => route('cancel'),
        ]);

    }
}


routes:
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CheckoutController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

Route::get('/success', function () {
    return view('success');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'payingCustomer'])->name('success');

Route::get('/cancel', function () {
    return view('cancel');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('cancel');

Route::get('/checkout/{plan?}', CheckoutController::class
)->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('checkout');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

Route::get('/subscribe', function () {
    return view('subscribe');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('subscribe');

Route::get('/members', function () {
    return view('members');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'payingCustomer'])->name('members');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

i tried almost everything given on the internet, chatgpt etc, the only problem i am facing is with
if ($request->user() && ! $request->user()->subscribed('prod_QbjA3oKZmzyBAj')) {
            // This user is not a paying customer...
            return redirect('subscribe');
        }

specifically subscribed('prod_QbjA3oKZmzyBAj')

As seen in the documentation - Did you want to use $user->subscribedToProduct('product_code') instead?

Log it. Inside of that function, try Log::info($request->user()->id); Log::info($request->user()->subscribed('prod_QbjA3oKZmzyBAj')); and see what you get in your log
